# Integer multiplication overflow

Tags: objective-c, integer, overflow, long-integer

I have problem with multiplying two integers in Objective C. When I multiply 500 with 20000000 and save in a long variable and print it the result is **1410065408**.

```
int x = 500;
long myLongValue = x * 20000000;
NSLog(@" %lu",myLongValue);
```

I think the problem is about overflowing integers, but I couldn't find real reason. I try to find the real result 10000000000, using multiplication of these integers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an overflow here : an unsigned int is coded using 32bits, so the max value will be 2^32-1, 4294967295. An int is coded using 31 bits (1 bit is for the sign), and the max will be 2147483647.

[image]

As you can see here, the 33h bit is used to represent your number, so you cannot represent it with an int. Guess which number you'll get if you set this bit to 0 ? ;)

[image]

**SOLUTION EDITED** : Even if you assign the result to a long value, the result is first stored into an int, so you should cast your values to long before performing the multiplication in objC. Also, as rmaddy noticed in the comments, using a `long` variable doesn't work in 32bit architecture since `long`is coded using 4bytes. You should use `long long` type instead, or use explicit types such as int32_t and int64_t.

```
int x = 500;
long long myLongValue = (long long)x * 20000000;
NSLog(@" %llu",myLongValue);    // logs correctly 10000000000
```

You can also declare your `x` directly as a `long long` variable.

**FYI :** swift is not as tolerant as objC, and your example code will crash because of the 'out-of range' bit :

```
let a:Int32 = 20000000
let b:Int32 = 500

let result = a*b                    // CRASH
let result2 = Int64(a)*Int64(b)     // OK
```

Comment: The question is about Objective-C. It's best to post answers in Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, the last paragraph about swift was meant to show that this new language is less prone to casting errors at runtime since you got the errors when compiling.

Comment: OK, but an actual answer to the question will include a proper solution in the appropriate language. Keep the Swift to demonstrate the issue but add a solution in Objective-C that fixes the problem.

Comment: The answer in objC was added :)

Comment: Strange. When I run the posted solution on a 5th gen iPod touch, it still shows the wrong answer. I needed to change `myLongValue` and the cast to `long long` to see the correct answer.

Comment: Got it, `long` is coded using 4bytes in 32bits architecture, and the 5th gen iPod touch uses an 32bits arm9 chip. `long long` uses 8 bytes in 32bits architecture, so it works in your perfectly. I'll add some information in the answer about it. Thanks for pointing it out.   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html

Comment: FYI - an alternative to casting `x` to a `long long` is to add `ll` (double ell) to the end of the constant as follows: `20000000ll`. Either approach works.